# Updating java from IBM to Oracle

Tags: xubuntu, java

I have IBM java installed on my xubuntu 12.04 machine.I want to change it to oracle java.I downloaded jdk1.7.0_45 and extracted it to `/usr/local/java`.Then I edited the `/etc/profile` file as follows:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

and then executed the command  `. /etc/profile`.But when I do `java -version` it still shows IBM java and `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` does not list oracle java.
I badly need oracle java as android sdk does not support IBM java.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to install **Oracle Java** in Ubuntu is to use the **PPA** from **WebUpd8**. Open **Terminal** and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

The installer from **WebUpd8** will download **Oracle Java** from the **Java** official site and install it for you.

Be sure you have removed your other version of **Java** before installing the new one.

Then use `java -version` to see if everything is precise.

Comment: Thanks.After installing Oracle Java as you said, I am getting it enlisted in javac alternatives.But even after selecting Oracle Java,when i run java -version still I get IBM java.